# Stripe - Get Prices and their Payment Links

Tags: c#, stripe-payments

I am trying to build a subscription page like like

[image: Payment Layout]

I have a `GetPrices` method to get my Stripe prices and have included the Price Product information too.

```
public StripeList<Price> GetPrices()
{
    StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = Options.SecretKey;

    var service = new PriceService();

    var priceListOption = new PriceListOptions
    {
        Limit = 3,
        Active = true
    };

    priceListOption.AddExpand("data.product");

    return service.List(options: priceListOption);
}
```

I also have a `GetPaymentLinks` method which just returns a `count` number of `PaymentLinks`.

```
public StripeList<PaymentLink> GetPaymentLinks(int count)
{
    StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = Options.SecretKey;

    var paymentLinkListOptions = new PaymentLinkListOptions
    {
        Limit = count,
        Active = true
    };

    var service = new PaymentLinkService();

    return service.List(paymentLinkListOptions);
}
```

What I can not seem to do is find the link between `Price/Product` and `PaymentLinks`

I can lookup through the list of `Prices` and display the Name, Description and Price. But I need to use the PaymentLink within the "Buy Now" button. Is there any way to do this with the Stripe Api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Price / Product would be found in the `line_items` array of your Payment Link(s).
https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_links/payment_links/object#payment_link_object-line_items
This array doesn't populate by default, you need to `expand` it:
https://stripe.com/docs/expand

If you want to expand both the Price and Product from this array, you can nest your expand == `data.line_items.data.price`.
That's the furthest you'll be able to go with a list because of that `data` prefix. In a Payment Link retrieve, you could go further with `line_items.data.price.product`.

Comment: This is the answer, thank you very much! With expanding data you cant go more than 3 levels but i can get the product details separately